# How to reproduce Spectrogram from SpectrogramArray?

Tags: plotting, sound, signal-processing

I'm trying to reproduce the result of [`Spectrogram`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Spectrogram.html) from [`SpectrogramArray`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SpectrogramArray.html), but having no luck, any help?

What I've got so far:

```
x = "some-audio.wav";
colorFunc = (Blend[{White, Orange, Red, Black}, #] &);

(* The spectrogram plotted by the Spectrogram function *)
Spectrogram[
 Audio[x], 400, 160, HammingWindow, ColorFunction -> colorFunc, 
 Frame -> None]

(* Trying to reproduce it *)
spect = SpectrogramArray[Audio[x], 400, 160, HammingWindow];
half = spect[[All, 1 ;; Dimensions[spect][[2]]/2]];
data = Abs[half];
ArrayPlot[Reverse@Transpose[data], AspectRatio -> 1/3, Frame -> None, 
 ColorFunction -> colorFunc]
```

The result:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried  `InverseSpectrogram[ data ]`  ?

Comment: Might be a headache, there’s a lot of preprocessing and formatting logic inside Spectrogram

Comment: @M.R. do you have access to the `Spectrogram` source code?

Comment: @Incömplete Just do this: <<GeneralUtilities`; PrintDefinitions[Spectrogram]

Comment: @M.R. The actual definition is not printed by it, it just prints the options of the function, and some other stuff.

Comment: @Incömplete To  see the source you need to do this: `Unprotect[Spectrogram]; ClearAttributes[Spectrogram, ReadProtected]; ` and then click on the `iSpectrogram` hyperlink.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways, both showing the same result. I use the sound of an empty glass when hitting a side surface - see [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/214279/3d-elastic-waves-in-a-glass/214341?noredirect=1#comment548829_214341)

```
x=AudioCapture["C:\\Users\\...\\Desktop\\\\glass0.wav", MaxDuration -> 2]
colorFunc = (Blend[{White, Orange, Red, Black}, #] &);

(*The spectrogram plotted by the Spectrogram function*)
Spectrogram[Audio[x], 400, 160, HammingWindow, 
 ColorFunction -> colorFunc, FrameTicks -> None]

(*Trying to reproduce it*)
spect = SpectrogramArray[Audio[x], 400, 160, HammingWindow];
half = spect[[All, 1 ;; Dimensions[spect][[2]]/2]];
data = Abs[half];
ArrayPlot[Reverse@Transpose[data], AspectRatio -> 1/3, 
 ColorFunction -> colorFunc, FrameTicks -> None, 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False]
(* Second way*)
ListDensityPlot[Transpose[Abs[spect]][[;; 200]], AspectRatio -> 1/3, 
 PlotRange -> All, ColorFunction -> colorFunc, 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False, FrameTicks -> None]
```

[image: Figure 1]

Comment: Unfortunately, the two graphs doesn't look the same. I also tried on my data, it doesn't look the same either