# 3D Elastic waves in a glass

Tags: equation-solving, finite-element-method

Take an empty glass, hit the side, the glass will make a sound that can be recorded using

```
s0=AudioCapture["C:\\Users\\...\\Desktop\\\\glass0.wav", MaxDuration -> 2]
```

Find the sound spectrum

```
Spectrogram[s0]
```

The photo shows a glass and a spectrum of sound 
[image: Figure 1]

Now we measure the dimensions of the glass, take the density, Young's modulus, glass Poisson's ratio from the reference book, compose the equations and find the eigenvalues

```
<< NDSolve`FEM`;
L = .14; L1 = .01; r1 = .085/2; r2 = .055/
  2; del = .006;(*cg=3962 m/s, 3980, 5100, 5640*);
reg = RegionUnion[
   ImplicitRegion[(r2 + (r1 - r2) (z - L1)/(L - L1))^2 <= 
      x^2 + y^2 <= (r2 + (r1 - r2) (z - L1)/(L - L1) + del)^2 && 
     L1 <= z <= L, {x, y, z}], 
   ImplicitRegion[
    0 <= x^2 + y^2 <= (r2 + del)^2 && 0 <= z <= L1, {x, y, z}]];
param = {Y -> 56*10^9, ν -> 25/100}; rho = 2500;
ClearAll[stressOperator];
stressOperator[
   Y_, ν_] := {Inactive[
      Div][{{0, 0, -((Y*ν)/((1 - 2*ν)*(1 + ν)))}, {0, 0, 
        0}, {-Y/(2*(1 + ν)), 0, 0}}.Inactive[Grad][
       w[t, x, y, z], {x, y, z}], {x, y, z}] + 
    Inactive[
      Div][{{0, -((Y*ν)/((1 - 2*ν)*(1 + ν))), 
        0}, {-Y/(2*(1 + ν)), 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}}.Inactive[Grad][
       v[t, x, y, z], {x, y, z}], {x, y, z}] + 
    Inactive[
      Div][{{-((Y*(1 - ν))/((1 - 2*ν)*(1 + ν))), 0, 
        0}, {0, -Y/(2*(1 + ν)), 0}, {0, 
        0, -Y/(2*(1 + ν))}}.Inactive[Grad][
       u[t, x, y, z], {x, y, z}], {x, y, z}], 
   Inactive[
      Div][{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 
        0, -((Y*ν)/((1 - 
               2*ν)*(1 + ν)))}, {0, -Y/(2*(1 + ν)), 
        0}}.Inactive[Grad][w[t, x, y, z], {x, y, z}], {x, y, z}] + 
    Inactive[
      Div][{{0, -Y/(2*(1 + ν)), 
        0}, {-((Y*ν)/((1 - 2*ν)*(1 + ν))), 0, 0}, {0, 0, 
        0}}.Inactive[Grad][u[t, x, y, z], {x, y, z}], {x, y, z}] + 
    Inactive[
      Div][{{-Y/(2*(1 + ν)), 0, 
        0}, {0, -((Y*(1 - ν))/((1 - 2*ν)*(1 + ν))), 
        0}, {0, 0, -Y/(2*(1 + ν))}}.Inactive[Grad][
       v[t, x, y, z], {x, y, z}], {x, y, z}], 
   Inactive[
      Div][{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 
        0, -Y/(2*(1 + ν))}, {0, -((Y*ν)/((1 - 
               2*ν)*(1 + ν))), 0}}.Inactive[Grad][
       v[t, x, y, z], {x, y, z}], {x, y, z}] + 
    Inactive[
      Div][{{0, 0, -Y/(2*(1 + ν))}, {0, 0, 
        0}, {-((Y*ν)/((1 - 2*ν)*(1 + ν))), 0, 
        0}}.Inactive[Grad][u[t, x, y, z], {x, y, z}], {x, y, z}] + 
    Inactive[
      Div][{{-Y/(2*(1 + ν)), 0, 0}, {0, -Y/(2*(1 + ν)), 
        0}, {0, 0, -((Y*(1 - ν))/((1 - 
               2*ν)*(1 + ν)))}}.Inactive[Grad][
       w[t, x, y, z], {x, y, z}], {x, y, z}]};

{vals, funs} = 
 NDEigensystem[
  stressOperator[56*10^9, 1/4] + 
    rho {D[u[t, x, y, z], {t, 2}], D[v[t, x, y, z], {t, 2}], 
      D[w[t, x, y, z], {t, 2}]} == {0, 0, 0}, {u, v, w}, 
  t, {x, y, z} ∈ reg, 15];
```

Frequencies in Hertz

```
Abs[vals ]/(2 Pi)

Out[9]= {0.000389602, 0.000865814, 0.000865814, 0.000921462, \
0.000921462, 0.00136215, 0.00136215, 0.00152256, 0.00152256, \
0.0015598, 0.0015598, 2140.67, 2140.67, 2144.36, 2144.36}
```

And so we see that frequencies 2140-2144 explain the result of our experiment (in the spectrogram, the peak is about 2000 H). Build 3D functions `u,v,w` for frequency 2144.36

```
DensityPlot3D[Re[funs[[15, 1]][x, y, z]], {x, y, z} ∈ reg, 
 ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", OpacityFunction -> None, Boxed -> False, 
 PlotLabel -> Row[{"f = ", Abs[vals [[15]]]/2/Pi}], 
 BoxRatios -> Automatic, PlotPoints -> 50]

DensityPlot3D[Re[funs[[15, 2]][x, y, z]], {x, y, z} ∈ reg, 
 ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", OpacityFunction -> None, Boxed -> False, 
 PlotLabel -> Row[{"f = ", Abs[vals [[15]]]/2/Pi}], 
 BoxRatios -> Automatic, PlotPoints -> 50]
DensityPlot3D[Re[funs[[15, 3]][x, y, z]], {x, y, z} ∈ reg, 
 ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", Boxed -> False, 
 PlotLabel -> Row[{"f = ", Abs[vals [[15]]]/2/Pi}], 
 BoxRatios -> Automatic, PlotPoints -> 50]
```

[image: Fig2]

OK! Problems arise if we put `del=0.003` (real glass wall thickness). First, the desired frequencies  2140-2144H disappear. Secondly, the 3D functions `u,v,w` look as if there are holes in the glass
[image: Figure3]

Is it possible to get the desired result for `del=.003`?

Update 1. We use the algorithm proposed by user21 with a small modification and with the boundary condition `DirichletCondition[{u[t, x, y, z] == 0, v[t, x, y, z] == 0, 
  w[t, x, y, z] == 0}, z == 0]`. Then the first 5 modes are consistent with the experiment (15 modes can be calculated with an error):

```
<< NDSolve`FEM`;
L = 0.14; L1 = 0.01; r1 = 0.085/2; r2 = 0.055/2; del = 0.003;


reg = RegionUnion[
   ImplicitRegion[(r2 + (r1 - r2) (z - L1)/(L - L1))^2 <= 
      x^2 + y^2 <= (r2 + (r1 - r2) (z - L1)/(L - L1) + del)^2 && 
     L1 <= z <= L, {x, y, z}], 
   ImplicitRegion[
    0 <= x^2 + y^2 <= (r2 + del)^2 && 0 <= z <= L1, {x, y, z}]];
(mesh = ToElementMesh[reg, 
    "BoundaryMeshGenerator" -> {"BoundaryDiscretizeRegion", 
      Method -> {"MarchingCubes", PlotPoints -> 31}}, 
    "MeshOrder" -> 1])["Wireframe"]
```

Modes

```
{vals, funs} = 
 NDEigensystem[{stressOperator[56*10^9, 1/4] + 
     rho {D[u[t, x, y, z], {t, 2}], D[v[t, x, y, z], {t, 2}], 
       D[w[t, x, y, z], {t, 2}]} == {0, 0, 0}, 
   DirichletCondition[{u[t, x, y, z] == 0, v[t, x, y, z] == 0, 
     w[t, x, y, z] == 0}, z == 0]}, {u, v, w}, 
  t, {x, y, z} \[Element] mesh, 5];
```

Modes in Hz

```
Abs[vals]/(2 Pi)

Out[]= {2047.63, 2048.03, 2048.03, 2336.35, 2336.35}
```

There are radial and azimuthal modes
[image: Figure4]

Update 2. We use the algorithm proposed by Pinti with a modification and with the boundary condition `DirichletCondition[{u[t, x, y, z] == 0, v[t, x, y, z] == 0, 
  w[t, x, y, z] == 0}, y == 0]`. Then the first 9 modes are consistent with the experiment (modes can be calculated without an error):

```
Get["MeshTools`"]

L = 0.14; L1 = 0.01; r1 = 0.085/2; r2 = 0.055/2; del = 0.003;

n1 = 5;
n2 = 31;
n3 = 5;
n4 = 12;
mesh2D = StructuredMesh[{{{r2, 0}, {r1, L}}, {{r2 - del, 
     0}, {r1 - del, L}}}, {n2, n1}]

mesh2D["Wireframe"[Axes -> True, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]]
```

Modes

```
{vals, funs} = 
 NDEigensystem[{stressOperator[56*10^9, 1/4] + 
     rho {D[u[t, x, y, z], {t, 2}], D[v[t, x, y, z], {t, 2}], 
       D[w[t, x, y, z], {t, 2}]} == {0, 0, 0}, 
   DirichletCondition[{u[t, x, y, z] == 0, v[t, x, y, z] == 0, 
     w[t, x, y, z] == 0}, y == 0]}, {u, v, w}, 
  t, {x, y, z} \[Element] mesh, 9];
```

`vals` in Hz

```
     Abs[vals]/(2 Pi)

Out[]= {23.1411, 1806.36, 1806.36, 1806.36, 1806.36, 1970.47, \
1970.47, 1970.58, 1970.58}
```

There are radial and azimuthal modes too
[image: Figure 5]

Update 3. We use the algorithm proposed by user21 for version 12.1 with a small modification

```
<< NDSolve`FEM`;
L = 0.14; L1 = 0.01; del = 0.003; r1 = 0.085/2; r2 = 0.055/2;

polygon = 
  Polygon[{{0, 0, 0}, {r2 + del, 0, 0}, {r2 + del, 0, L1}, {r1 + del, 
     0, L}, {r1, 0, L}, {r2, 0, L1}, {0, 0, L1}}];

Needs["OpenCascadeLink`"]
shape = OpenCascadeShape[polygon];
axis = {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 3/2 L}}; sweep = 
 OpenCascadeShapeRotationalSweep[shape, axis, 2 Pi];
bmesh = OpenCascadeShapeSurfaceMeshToBoundaryMesh[sweep, 
   "ShapeSurfaceMeshOptions" -> {"LinearDeflection" -> 0.0003}];


mesh = ToElementMesh[bmesh, AccuracyGoal -> 5, PrecisionGoal -> 5, 
  "MeshOrder" -> 1];


param = {Y -> 56*10^9, \[Nu] -> 25/100}; rho = 2500; cg = 
 Sqrt[56.*10^9/rho]; 


ClearAll[stressOperator];
stressOperator[
   Y_, \[Nu]_] := {Inactive[
      Div][{{0, 0, -((Y*\[Nu])/((1 - 2*\[Nu])*(1 + \[Nu])))}, {0, 0, 
        0}, {-Y/(2*(1 + \[Nu])), 0, 0}}.Inactive[Grad][
       w[t, x, y, z], {x, y, z}], {x, y, z}] + 
    Inactive[
      Div][{{0, -((Y*\[Nu])/((1 - 2*\[Nu])*(1 + \[Nu]))), 
        0}, {-Y/(2*(1 + \[Nu])), 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}}.Inactive[Grad][
       v[t, x, y, z], {x, y, z}], {x, y, z}] + 
    Inactive[
      Div][{{-((Y*(1 - \[Nu]))/((1 - 2*\[Nu])*(1 + \[Nu]))), 0, 
        0}, {0, -Y/(2*(1 + \[Nu])), 0}, {0, 
        0, -Y/(2*(1 + \[Nu]))}}.Inactive[Grad][
       u[t, x, y, z], {x, y, z}], {x, y, z}], 
   Inactive[
      Div][{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 
        0, -((Y*\[Nu])/((1 - 
               2*\[Nu])*(1 + \[Nu])))}, {0, -Y/(2*(1 + \[Nu])), 
        0}}.Inactive[Grad][w[t, x, y, z], {x, y, z}], {x, y, z}] + 
    Inactive[
      Div][{{0, -Y/(2*(1 + \[Nu])), 
        0}, {-((Y*\[Nu])/((1 - 2*\[Nu])*(1 + \[Nu]))), 0, 0}, {0, 0, 
        0}}.Inactive[Grad][u[t, x, y, z], {x, y, z}], {x, y, z}] + 
    Inactive[
      Div][{{-Y/(2*(1 + \[Nu])), 0, 
        0}, {0, -((Y*(1 - \[Nu]))/((1 - 2*\[Nu])*(1 + \[Nu]))), 
        0}, {0, 0, -Y/(2*(1 + \[Nu]))}}.Inactive[Grad][
       v[t, x, y, z], {x, y, z}], {x, y, z}], 
   Inactive[
      Div][{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 
        0, -Y/(2*(1 + \[Nu]))}, {0, -((Y*\[Nu])/((1 - 
               2*\[Nu])*(1 + \[Nu]))), 0}}.Inactive[Grad][
       v[t, x, y, z], {x, y, z}], {x, y, z}] + 
    Inactive[
      Div][{{0, 0, -Y/(2*(1 + \[Nu]))}, {0, 0, 
        0}, {-((Y*\[Nu])/((1 - 2*\[Nu])*(1 + \[Nu]))), 0, 
        0}}.Inactive[Grad][u[t, x, y, z], {x, y, z}], {x, y, z}] + 
    Inactive[
      Div][{{-Y/(2*(1 + \[Nu])), 0, 0}, {0, -Y/(2*(1 + \[Nu])), 
        0}, {0, 0, -((Y*(1 - \[Nu]))/((1 - 
               2*\[Nu])*(1 + \[Nu])))}}.Inactive[Grad][
       w[t, x, y, z], {x, y, z}], {x, y, z}]};

{vals, funs} = 
 NDEigensystem[{stressOperator[56*10^9, 1/4] + 
     rho {D[u[t, x, y, z], {t, 2}], D[v[t, x, y, z], {t, 2}], 
       D[w[t, x, y, z], {t, 2}]} == {0, 0, 0}, 
   DirichletCondition[{u[t, x, y, z] == 0, v[t, x, y, z] == 0, 
     w[t, x, y, z] == 0}, z == 0]}, {u, v, w}, 
  t, {x, y, z} \[Element] mesh, 12];
```

`vals` in Hz

```
     Abs[vals]/(2 Pi)
```

{1973.97, 1973.97, 1974.86, 1974.86, 2169.47, 2169.47, 2250.23, 2250.23, 4183.69, 4183.69, 5532.12, 5532.12}
Visualisation of 3 modes

```
DensityPlot3D[Re[funs[[1, 1]][x, y, z]], {x, y, z} \[Element] mesh, 
 ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", OpacityFunction -> None, Boxed -> False, 
 PlotLabel -> Row[{"f = ", Abs[vals [[1]]]/2/Pi}], 
 BoxRatios -> Automatic, PlotPoints -> 50]
DensityPlot3D[Re[funs[[5, 1]][x, y, z]], {x, y, z} \[Element] mesh, 
 ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", OpacityFunction -> None, Boxed -> False, 
 PlotLabel -> Row[{"f = ", Abs[vals [[5]]]/2/Pi}], 
 BoxRatios -> Automatic, PlotPoints -> 50]
DensityPlot3D[Re[funs[[7, 1]][x, y, z]], {x, y, z} \[Element] mesh, 
 ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", OpacityFunction -> None, Boxed -> False, 
 PlotLabel -> Row[{"f = ", Abs[vals [[7]]]/2/Pi}], 
 BoxRatios -> Automatic, PlotPoints -> 50]
```

[image: Figure 7]

Comment: I was wondering if you would like to contribute this model to the [FEMAddOns](https://github.com/WolframResearch/FEMAddOns). There is a section for [Application examples](https://github.com/WolframResearch/FEMAddOns/tree/master/FEMAddOns/Applications/Documentation/English/Tutorials). Might be a nice contribution. Just a thought.

Comment: @user21 Thank you for your proposal. I have tried several times to contribute something on github with .nb extension, but never successful. I don't understand how it is working. If you can, please, do it.

Comment: We could do it together if you want. If you could send me an initial draft of your work notebook we can take it from there,

Comment: @user21 Are you talking about last code with `"OpenCascade Link`"` using?

Comment: Whatever you think is appropriate to get a good result.

Comment: @user21 Ok! I sent you 3 files at wolfram.com.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You get a better mesh with a different boundary mesh generator:

```
(mesh = ToElementMesh[reg, 
    "BoundaryMeshGenerator" -> \
{"BoundaryDiscretizeRegion",
      Method -> {"MarchingCubes", PlotPoints -> 33}}, 
    "MeshOrder" -> 1,
    "MaxCellMeasure"\[Rule]0.000000005])["Wireframe"]
```

[image]

For that mesh I get

```
Abs[vals]/(2 Pi)
(*{0.000502385, 0.000502385, 0.00072869, 0.00072869, \
0.000733392, 0.000733392, 0.0010404, 0.0010404, 0.00150767, \
0.00150767, 0.00151325, 0.00151325, 0.308656, 2238.88, 2238.88}*)
```

And the 14th mode looks like:

```
MeshRegion[
 ElementMeshDeformation[mesh, Re[Through[funs[[14]]["ValuesOnGrid"]]],
   "ScalingFactor" -> 10^9]]
```

[image]

Two other comments: the fact that NDEigensystem gives messages suggests to me that this mesh is still not good enough; as you see I also used `MeshOrder->1` as I did not want to wait for a second order mesh to finish. But you might want to try that and a finer mesh. Probably by using more plot points. Perhaps generate the boundary mesh manually?

A second thing that come to mind is that I think you should have some rigid body modes because the glass stands on the table. Maybe experiment with

```
DirichletCondition[{u[t, x, y, z] == 0, v[t, x, y, z] == 0, 
  w[t, x, y, z] == 0}, x == 0]
```

Also, there is a nice Bell Acoustics customer example in the [FEMAddOns](https://github.com/WolframResearch/FEMAddOns). You can install that with

```
ResourceFunction["FEMAddOnsInstall"][]
```

and find it on the Applications guide page

```
FEMAddOns/guide/FEMApplications
```

or have a look at the cloud version of that [notebook](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/github-cloud/blobs/e55af7e9216711be5a312d3ed6dd8e448775435a).

Hope this helps.

**Update: 12.1**

Another way to generate the mesh is to make use of the [OpenCascadeLink](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/OpenCascadeLink/tutorial/UsingOpenCascadeLink.html). For this we generate a flat cross section of the glass in 3D.

```
polygon = 
  Polygon[{{0, 0, 0}, {r2 + del, 0, 0}, {r2 + del, 0, L1}, {r1 + del, 
     0, L}, {r1, 0, L}, {r2, 0, L1}, {0, 0, L1}}];
Graphics3D[{FaceForm[], EdgeForm[Black], polygon}, Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

We load the link

```
Needs["OpenCascadeLink`"]
```

and convert the polygon into an OCCT shape:

```
shape = OpenCascadeShape[polygon];
```

We set up an axis of revolution and sweep the polygon.

```
axis = {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 3/2 L}};
sweep = OpenCascadeShapeRotationalSweep[shape, axis, 2 \[Pi]];
```

Here is a visual of the result:

```
bmesh = OpenCascadeShapeSurfaceMeshToBoundaryMesh[sweep, 
   "ShapeSurfaceMeshOptions" -> {"LinearDeflection" -> 0.00125}];
Show[Graphics3D[{{Red, polygon}, {Blue, Thick, Arrow[axis]}}], 
 bmesh["Wireframe"], Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

You see the original polygon in red and the blue arrow is the rotational axis. From here we can generate the mesh in the same way:

```
mesh = ToElementMesh[bmesh, "MeshOrder" -> 1(*,
  "MaxCellMeasure"\[Rule]0.000000005*)]

mesh["Wireframe"[
  "MeshElementStyle" -> 
   Directive[Opacity[0.2], Specularity[White, 17], FaceForm[White], 
    EdgeForm[]]]]
```

[image]

This is a much better approximation of the geometry. Nevertheless finding the eigenvalues remains challenging as there is a strong dependency of the eigenvalues on the mesh.

Comment: Thank you for the mesh (+1) and links. They also use a thick cylinder. I will try to create a thin glass manually.

Comment: Finite element codes often have shell elements. It looks like they would be useful here.  Is there any chance of getting such elements available in Mathematica?

Comment: @Hugh, sorry I saw the comment but then forgot to reply. Shell elements are currently not planed. There is still too much other stuff I can improve before going down this alley.

Comment: @user21 thank you. This is a very interesting update in version 12.1. I'll check how it works.

Comment: @user21 See update to my post.

Comment: @AlexTrounev, what do you think, seems reasonable?

Comment: @user21 Yes, this is a good method for building a 3D mesh. It will be necessary to test on other problems.

Answer (score 11):

[MeshTools](https://github.com/c3m-labs/MeshTools) package can help insituations where we need fine control of mesh density and shape.

First we define a 2D mesh for glass outline and revolve it around vertical axis. Then we merge it with cylinder mesh for glass bottom. We get 1st order mesh, but it can be converted to 2 order with `MeshOrderAlteration` from `` "NDSolve`FEM`" `` built-in package.

```
Get["MeshTools`"]

L = 0.14; L1 = 0.01; r1 = 0.085/2; r2 = 0.055/2; del = 0.003;

n1 = 2;
n2 = 40;
n3 = 5;
n4 = 12;
mesh2D = MergeMesh[{
   StructuredMesh[{{{r2, L1}, {r1, L}}, {{r2 - del, L1}, {r1 - del, L}}}, {n2, n1}],
   StructuredMesh[{{{r2, 0}, {r2, L1}}, {{r2 - del, 0}, {r2 - del,  L1}}}, {n3, n1}]
 }]

mesh2D["Wireframe"[Axes -> True, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]]
```

[image: mesh2D]

```
mesh = MergeMesh[{
   CylinderMesh[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, L1, 0}}, r2 - del, {n4, n1}],
   RevolveMesh[mesh2D, {0, 2 Pi}, 4*n4]
 }]
(* ElementMesh[{{-0.0425,0.0425},{0.,0.14},{-0.0425,0.0425}}, {HexahedronElement["<"4896">"]}]*)


mesh["Wireframe"["MeshElementStyle" -> FaceForm@LightBlue]]
```

[image: mesh3D]

For the calculated frequencies we get the following list.

```
Abs[vals]/(2 Pi)
(*{0.000290029, 0.000355687, 0.000355687, 0.000584401, 0.000584401, 0.000724522, 0.000724522, 0.000903912, 0.000903912, 0.000903912, 0.000903912, 1907.22, 1907.22, 1907.6, 1907.6}*)
```

Comment: (+1) nice. How many elements does the final mesh have? And I assume it is first order?

Comment: @Pint (+1) Looks good, but how did you find `vals`? My kernel is breaking on this mesh with using `NDEigenvalues[]` or `NDEigensystem[]`

Comment: @AlexTrounev Before I have copied wrong set of mesh division settings. These current settings work for me on Windows, MMa 12. For many other combinations of element division kernel also dies on me. I don't know why.

Comment: @Pinti Unfortunately, this mesh also does not work in version 12 for Windows 10 64 bit. However, I found many other combinations of `n1,n2,n3,n4` that work, but none of them give the desired frequencies.

Comment: @Pinti I managed to find a combination of mesh parameters on which `NDEigensystem[]` finds the modes without errors - see update2.

Comment: @AlexTrounev That is great news! I am glad to help.