Solving a stiff non-linear initial value ODE for a set of parameters
I want to solve a fairly simple system of non-linearly couple ODEs that comes from a physical problem conceptually similar to Landau-Zener transitions in optics.
The equations, with initial conditions, are
Eqs = {
Z'[t] == -(8/3) (1 + co R v[t] Z[t]^(1/8)), 
u'[t] == tb (G u[t] - A v[t] (B w[t] + 35 (L x[t] + M (1 - co/Z[t]^(3/8))))), 
v'[t] == tb (G v[t] + A u[t] (B w[t] + 35 (L x[t] + M (1 - co/Z[t]^(3/8)))) - ( H w[t])/Z[t]^(3/4)), 
w'[t] == tb (G w[t] - G x[t] + (H v[t])/Z[t]^(3/4)),
x'[t] == tb (-G w[t] + G x[t]),
Z[0] == (1/10)^(-8/3),
u[0] == 0,
v[0] == 0,
w[0] == 1,
x[0] == 1,
WhenEvent[Z[t] < (3/2)^(-8/3), "StopIntegration"; tfin = t]}; 

I stop integrating when the value of Z reaches (3/2)^(-8/3). I use the NDSolve function
sol = NDSolve[Eqs, {Z, u, v, w, x}, {t, 0, tfin},
   Method -> {"StiffnessSwitching"},
   WorkingPrecision -> 15,
   MaxSteps -> 100000];

For the following set of parameters (rationalized to increase the precision)
tb = Rationalize[3.37451622280346`*^10 , 0];
G = Rationalize[-6.130474712095433`*^-7, 0];
R = Rationalize[34642.904529141015, 0];
A = Rationalize[1.296322837613374`*^-8, 0];
B = Rationalize[-9.707867`*^6, 0];
H = Rationalize[0.000015464192561092353, 0];
L = 92105;
M = 442368;
co = 1;
tfin = 174;

the solver is able to work out the solution easily and I get something that makes sense physically. Here is a plot of the solution for the parameters of interest in the final part of the integration.

The orange line represents where a resonance appears, i.e. when the term proportional to v[t] in the u'[t] equation (and, same, proportional to u[t] in the v'[t]) becomes zero.
Zres = x /. Solve[(B + 35 (L + M (1 - co/x^(3/8)))) == 0, x];

Now, consider this other set of parameters
tb = Rationalize[3.843928851723783`*^13, 0] ;
G = Rationalize[-2.4968635835484115`*^-9, 0];
R = Rationalize[444693.9470717366`, 0];
A = Rationalize[1.6102471715083507`*^-8, 0];
B = Rationalize[-3.473457`*^6, 0];
H = Rationalize[2.945784520040484`*^-7, 0];
L = 32955;
M = 32768;

tfin = 174;
co = -1;

While the values change, this is not so crucial. The most important change is that the parameter co = -1, in such a way that a value for Zres can be still found.
However, for these parameters the system becomes stiff when Z approaches Zres=0.941391:
NDSolve: At t == 173.69909246107732827781555865465052721598`15.,
step size is effectively zero;
singularity or stiff system suspected.

and the solver stops. The plots are now 
The output is clearly unphysical beyond the value of t signaled by NDSolve.
I would like to know how to get through the "resonance" for the second set of parameters or at least to get an understanding of what is going on, what causes the stiffness and possible solutions. I have already tried many Method options and several other tweaks, but they do not change the outcome.
EDIT
After an exchange with @AlexTrounev it is clear to me that the WhenEvent should not be the focus of the discussion. The obtained solution in the second set of parameter is not to be trusted because the solution depends on the final time. Somehow NDSolve does something I do not understand in the final steps and forcing the Z to be positive does not seem to work. I am trying another approach, suggested by @AlexTrounev.
I am getting rid of one equation using the parameter y = - Log[Z] as a time variable.
I am also using as an initial condition the eigenvector for the smallest eigenvalue close to the {0,0,1,1} initial condition that I expect far away. What I am doing is to linearize the system and considering {u',v',w',x'} = Mat * {u,v,w,x} far away from the resonance where {u,v,w,x}~{0,0,1,1}. I find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of Mat and choose as initial condition the eigenvector with the smallest eigenvalue. This slightly improves stability. Here is the code.
tb = Rationalize[3.37451622280346`*^10 , 0];
G = Rationalize[-6.130474712095433`*^-7, 0];
R = Rationalize[34642.904529141015, 0];
A = Rationalize[1.296322837613374`*^-8, 0];
B = Rationalize[-9.707867`*^6, 0];
H = Rationalize[0.000015464192561092353, 0];
L = 92105;
M = 442368;
co = 1;

Zini = (1/10)^(-8/3);
Zfin = (3/2)^(-8/3);
yini = -Log[Zini];
yfin = -Log[Zfin];
yini // N
yfin // N
Zres = x /. Solve[(B + 35 (L + M (1 - co/x^(3/8)))) == 0, x][[1]] // N;
yres = -Log[Zres]

Mat = {{G, -A (B + 35 (L + M (1 - co/ (E^(-3 yini/8))))), 0, 0},
   {A (B + 35 (L + M (1 - co/ (E^(-3 yini/8))))), 
    G, -(H / (E^(-3 yini/4))), 0},
   {0, H / (E^(-3 yini/4)), G, -G},
   {0, 0, -G, G}};
magn = Abs[Eigenvalues[Mat]];
indx = Flatten[Position[magn, Min[magn]]];
eigenvec = Re[Flatten[Eigenvectors[Mat][[indx]]]];
Initial = {
   eigenvec[[1]]*eigenvec[[3]],
   eigenvec[[2]]*eigenvec[[3]],
   eigenvec[[3]]*eigenvec[[3]],
   eigenvec[[4]]*eigenvec[[3]]};



Eqs = {u'[
     y] == (-tb E^-y)/(-(8/3) (1 + co R v[y] E^(-y/8))) (G u[y] - 
       A v[y] (B w[y] + 35 (L x[y] + M (1 - co/ (E^(-3 y/8)))))), 
   v'[y] == (-tb E^-y)/(-(8/3) (1 + co R v[y] E^(-y/8))) (G v[y] + 
       A u[y] (B w[y] + 35 (L x[y] + M (1 - co/ (E^(-3 y/8))))) - ( 
       H w[y])/E^(-3 y/4)), 
   w'[y] == (-tb E^-y)/(-(8/3) (1 + co R v[y] E^(-y/8))) (G w[y] - 
       G x[y] + (H v[y])/E^(-3 y/4)),
   x'[y] == (-tb E^-y)/(-(8/3) (1 + co R v[y] E^(-y/8))) (-G w[y] + 
       G x[y]),
   u[yini] == Initial[[1]],
   v[yini] == Initial[[2]],
   w[yini] == Initial[[3]],
   x[yini] == Initial[[4]]};
sol = NDSolve[Eqs, {u, v, w, x}, {y, yini, yfin},
   MaxSteps -> 100000,
   Method -> {"StiffnessSwitching"},
   WorkingPrecision -> 20
   ];

This is Example 1 
and I get the result above (as expected).
In Example 2 (with the second set of parameters)
tb = Rationalize[3.843928851723783`*^13, 0] ;
G = Rationalize[-2.4968635835484115`*^-9, 0];
R = Rationalize[444693.9470717366`, 0];
A = Rationalize[1.6102471715083507`*^-8, 0];
B = Rationalize[-3.473457`*^6, 0];
H = Rationalize[2.945784520040484`*^-7, 0];
L = 32955;
M = 32768;

co = -1;

I cannot get past the resonance expected at y = 0.0603972
sol = NDSolve[Eqs, {u, v, w, x}, {y, yini, yfin},
   MaxSteps -> 100000,
   Method -> {"StiffnessSwitching"},
   WorkingPrecision -> 20
   ];

spits out At y == 0.04032368600458634190095706932222253824`20., step size is \ effectively zero; singularity or stiff system suspected
So i plot until that value 
What is actually going on, now that WhenEvent is not a problem anymore?

I get an error, "NDSolve::ndsz: At y == -6.14023, step size is effectively zero; singularity or stiff system suspected.", in Example 2. Quite possibly I do not understand what "Example 2" is. I had to execute code out of the order in which is presented. Using WorkingPrecision -> 20 gives different looking graphs. I'm confused.

Thanks for the comment @MichaelE2. I edited the question making the second part after the EDIT clearer, also providing the code fully. Please have a look!

@edinorog2196 Solution dependent on Z looks nice, but step with eigenvectors is not so clear.

@AlexTrounev I added a bit more of explanation. I am basically considering as initial condition the eigenvector (with the minimum eigenvalue~0) of the matrix that linearizes the system very far away from the resonance, where my initial condition is close, but not equal to {0,0,1,1}. This proves to improve stability and convergence. Notice that in the Example 2, it is not enough to get past the resonance.

@edinorog2196 Well, it seems that there is no improvement since Initial={-1.72835*10^-7, 0., 1., 1.} for Example 2. Also, on the last step at yc = 0.04032368600458634190102495023986818138 we have Eqs[[All, 2]] /. sol[[1]] /. y -> yc // N is about {-7.03296*10^6,   6.85464*10^10, 116782., -97339.2, -1.72835*10^-7, 0., 1., 1.}, therefore v'[yc]=6.85464*10^10. It is too much for any method of integration.

There is a typo with WhenEvent usage in the code. In the computation process Z becomes very small and negative that lids to the complex solution. Therefore the restriction Z[t] < (3/2)^(-8/3) does not work. To improve this, we use Re@Z[t] < (3/2)^(-8/3). In example 1, we took a time of 175 to test how WhenEvent works. Also note, that input parameters R, B are large, it why we reduce accuracy and precision.
 tb = Rationalize[3.37451622280346`*^10, 0];
G = Rationalize[-6.130474712095433`*^-7, 0];
R = Rationalize[34642.904529141015, 0];
A = Rationalize[1.296322837613374`*^-8, 0];
B = Rationalize[-9.707867`*^6, 0];
H = Rationalize[0.000015464192561092353, 0];
L = 92105;
M = 442368;
co = 1;
tfin = 175;

Eqs = {Z'[t] == -(8/3)  (1 + co  R  v[t]  Z[t]^(1/8)), 
   u'[t] == 
    tb  (G  u[t] - 
       A  v[t]  (B  w[t] + 35  (L  x[t] + M  (1 - co/Z[t]^(3/8))))), 
   v'[t] == 
    tb  (G  v[t] + 
       A  u[t]  (B  w[t] + 
          35  (L  x[t] + M  (1 - co/Z[t]^(3/8)))) - (H  w[t])/
        Z[t]^(3/4)), 
   w'[t] == tb  (G  w[t] - G  x[t] + (H  v[t])/Z[t]^(3/4)), 
   x'[t] == tb  (-G  w[t] + G  x[t]), Z[0] == (1/10)^(-8/3), 
   u[0] == 0, v[0] == 0, w[0] == 1, x[0] == 1, 
   WhenEvent[Re@Z[t] < (3/2)^(-8/3), tfin = t; "StopIntegration"]};

sol = NDSolve[Eqs, {Z, u, v, w, x}, {t, 0, tfin}, MaxSteps -> 100000, 
   AccuracyGoal -> 5, PrecisionGoal -> 8, 
   Method -> {"StiffnessSwitching"}];

Check final time
tfin

Out[]= 174.189

Check Z at final time
Z[t] /. sol[[1]] /. t -> tfin

Out[]= 0.339175 + 0. I

Please note that Z is complex number, and that (3./2)^(-8/3)=0.339175, therefore WhenEvent worked. Visualization
{Plot[Z[t] /. sol[[1]], {t, 0, tfin}, AxesLabel -> {"t", "Z"}],

Plot[(x[t] + w[t])/2 /. sol[[1]], {t, 0, tfin}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {"t", "(x+w)/2"}, PlotRange -> All]}


Example 2.
tb = Rationalize[3.843928851723783`*^13, 0] ;
G = Rationalize[-2.4968635835484115`*^-9, 0];
R = Rationalize[444693.9470717366`, 0];
A = Rationalize[1.6102471715083507`*^-8, 0];
B = Rationalize[-3.473457`*^6, 0];
H = Rationalize[2.945784520040484`*^-7, 0];
L = 32955;
M = 32768;

tfin = 175;
co = -1;
Eqs = {Z'[t] == -(8/3)  (1 + co  R  v[t]  Z[t]^(1/8)), 
   u'[t] == 
    tb  (G  u[t] - 
       A  v[t]  (B  w[t] + 35  (L  x[t] + M  (1 - co/Z[t]^(3/8))))), 
   v'[t] == 
    tb  (G  v[t] + 
       A  u[t]  (B  w[t] + 
          35  (L  x[t] + M  (1 - co/Z[t]^(3/8)))) - (H  w[t])/
        Z[t]^(3/4)), 
   w'[t] == tb  (G  w[t] - G  x[t] + (H  v[t])/Z[t]^(3/4)), 
   x'[t] == tb  (-G  w[t] + G  x[t]), Z[0] == (1/10)^(-8/3), 
   u[0] == 0, v[0] == 0, w[0] == 1, x[0] == 1, 
   WhenEvent[Re[Z[t]] < (3/2)^(-8/3), tfin = t; "StopIntegration"]};

sol1 = NDSolve[Eqs, {Z, u, v, w, x}, {t, 0, tfin}, MaxSteps -> 10^5, 
  AccuracyGoal -> 5, PrecisionGoal -> 6];

Check final time
tfin

Out[]= 173.932

Check Z at final time
Z[t] /. sol1[[1]] /. t -> tfin

Out[]= 0.339175 - 1.80719*10^-6 I

Visualization
{Plot[Re@Z[t] /. sol1[[1]], {t, 0, tfin}, AxesLabel -> {"t", "Z"}, 
  PlotRange -> All, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}], 
 Plot[Re@(x[t] + w[t])/2 /. sol1[[1]], {t, 0, tfin}, Frame -> True, 
  FrameLabel -> {"t", "(x+w)/2"}, PlotRange -> All]}


Here we also see a small peak in the left figure, which apparently corresponds to resonance.
Update 1. Second Example can be solved with FEM as follows
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"];

tb = Rationalize[3.843928851723783`*^13, 0];
G = Rationalize[-2.4968635835484115`*^-9, 0];
R = Rationalize[444693.9470717366`, 0];
A = Rationalize[1.6102471715083507`*^-8, 0];
B = Rationalize[-3.473457`*^6, 0];
H = Rationalize[2.945784520040484`*^-7, 0];
L = 32955;
M = 32768;

co = -1; Zini = (1/10)^(-8/3);
Zfin = (3/2)^(-8/3);
yini = -Log[Zini];
yfin = -Log[Zfin];
yini // N
yfin // N
Zres = x /. Solve[(B + 35 (L + M (1 - co/x^(3/8)))) == 0, x][[1]] // N;
yres = -Log[Zres]

Mat = {{G, -A (B + 35 (L + M (1 - co/(E^(-3 yini/8))))), 0, 
    0}, {A (B + 35 (L + M (1 - co/(E^(-3 yini/8))))), 
    G, -(H/(E^(-3 yini/4))), 0}, {0, H/(E^(-3 yini/4)), G, -G}, {0, 
    0, -G, G}};
magn = Abs[Eigenvalues[Mat]];
indx = Flatten[Position[magn, Min[magn]]];
eigenvec = Re[Flatten[Eigenvectors[Mat][[indx]]]];
Initial = {eigenvec[[1]]*eigenvec[[3]], eigenvec[[2]]*eigenvec[[3]], 
   eigenvec[[3]]*eigenvec[[3]], eigenvec[[4]]*eigenvec[[3]]};



Eqs = D[{-u'[
      y] + (-tb  E^-y)/(-(8/3) (1 + co R v[y] E^(-y/8)))  (G u[y] - 
       A v[y]  (B w[y] + 35 (L x[y] + M (1 - co/(E^(-3 y/8)))))), -v'[
      y] + (-tb  E^-y)/(-(8/3) (1 + co R v[y] E^(-y/8)))  (G v[y] + 
       A u[y] (B w[y] + 
          35 (L x[y] + M (1 - co/(E^(-3 y/8))))) - (H w[y])/
        E^(-3 y/4)), -w'[
      y] + (-tb  E^-y)/(-(8/3) (1 + co R v[y] E^(-y/8)))  (G w[y] - 
       G x[y] + (H v[y])/E^(-3 y/4)), -x'[
      y] + (-tb  E^-y)/(-(8/3) (1 + co R v[y] E^(-y/8)))  (-G w[y] + 
       G  x[y])}, y]; ic = 
 DirichletCondition[{u[y] == Initial[[1]], v[y] == Initial[[2]], 
   w[y] == Initial[[3]], x[y] == Initial[[4]]}, y == yini];

sol = NDSolve[{Table[Eqs[[i]] == 0, {i, 4}], ic}, {u, v, w, x}, {y, 
   yini, yfin}, 
  Method -> {"FiniteElement", 
    "InterpolationOrder" -> {u -> 2, v -> 2, w -> 2, x -> 2}, 
    "MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 10^-3}}]

Visualization
LogLogPlot[(w[-Log[Z]] + x[-Log[Z]])/2 /. sol[[1]], {Z, Zini, Zfin}, 
 PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"Z", (w + x)/2}]


Update 2. We can solve second problem without FEM as well. First, we run your code up to yc = 0.0403236860045863419010249502398681813820` where code stops, we have
tb = Rationalize[3.843928851723783`*^13, 0];
G = Rationalize[-2.4968635835484115`*^-9, 0];
R = Rationalize[444693.9470717366`, 0];
A = Rationalize[1.6102471715083507`*^-8, 0];
B = Rationalize[-3.473457`*^6, 0];
H = Rationalize[2.945784520040484`*^-7, 0];
L = 32955;
M = 32768;

co = -1; Zini = (1/10)^(-8/3);
Zfin = (3/2)^(-8/3);
yini = -Log[Zini];
yfin = -Log[Zfin];
Zres = x /. Solve[(B + 35 (L + M (1 - co/x^(3/8)))) == 0, x][[1]] // N;
yres = -Log[Zres]

Mat = {{G, -A (B + 35 (L + M (1 - co/(E^(-3 yini/8))))), 0, 
    0}, {A (B + 35 (L + M (1 - co/(E^(-3 yini/8))))), 
    G, -(H/(E^(-3 yini/4))), 0}, {0, H/(E^(-3 yini/4)), G, -G}, {0, 
    0, -G, G}};
magn = Abs[Eigenvalues[Mat]];
indx = Flatten[Position[magn, Min[magn]]];
eigenvec = Re[Flatten[Eigenvectors[Mat][[indx]]]];
Initial = {eigenvec[[1]]*eigenvec[[3]], eigenvec[[2]]*eigenvec[[3]], 
   eigenvec[[3]]*eigenvec[[3]], eigenvec[[4]]*eigenvec[[3]]};



Eqs = {u'[
     y] == (-tb E^-y)/(-(8/3) (1 + co R v[y] E^(-y/8))) (G u[y] - 
       A v[y] (B w[y] + 35 (L x[y] + M (1 - co/(E^(-3 y/8)))))), 
   v'[y] == (-tb E^-y)/(-(8/3) (1 + co R v[y] E^(-y/8))) (G v[y] + 
       A u[y] (B w[y] + 
          35 (L x[y] + M (1 - co/(E^(-3 y/8))))) - (H w[y])/
        E^(-3 y/4)), 
   w'[y] == (-tb E^-y)/(-(8/3) (1 + co R v[y] E^(-y/8))) (G w[y] - 
       G x[y] + (H v[y])/E^(-3 y/4)), 
   x'[y] == (-tb E^-y)/(-(8/3) (1 + co R v[y] E^(-y/8))) (-G w[y] + 
       G x[y]), u[yini] == Initial[[1]], v[yini] == Initial[[2]], 
   w[yini] == Initial[[3]], x[yini] == Initial[[4]]};
sol = NDSolve[Eqs, {u, v, w, x}, {y, yini, yfin}, MaxSteps -> 100000, 
  Method -> {"StiffnessSwitching"}, WorkingPrecision -> 20] 

Second, we redefine initial conditions as follows
yc = 0.04032368600458634190102495023986818138`20; ini = {u[
     y], v[y], w[y], x[y]} /. sol[[1]] /. y -> yc

(*Out[]= {0.05234472730875, 
 2.2590*10^-6, 0.9955004987451008, 0.9968757262022893}*)

Finally, we redefine equations and solve new system using any explicit solver, for example
dd = Rationalize[Eqs[[All, 2]] /. sol[[1]] /. y -> yc // N // Abs, 
   10^-30];

eqs1 = Drop[Eqs, -4] /. {u[y] -> dd[[1]] U[y], u'[y] -> dd[[1]] U'[y],
     v[y] -> dd[[2]] V[y], v'[y] -> dd[[2]] V'[y]};

sol1 = NDSolve[
  Join[eqs1, 
   Thread[{dd[[1]] U[y], dd[[2]] V[y], w[y], x[y]} == ini /. 
     y -> yc]], {U, V, w, x}, {y, yc, yfin}, 
  Method -> "ExplicitEuler", StartingStepSize -> 10^-5, 
  MaxSteps -> 2 10^5]

Visualization
LogLogPlot[#[t] /. sol1[[1]], {t, yc, yfin}, PlotRange -> All, 
   PlotLabel -> #] & /@ {U, V, w, x}


We also can use
ClassicalRungeKutta /: 
  NDSolve`InitializeMethod[ClassicalRungeKutta, __] := 
  ClassicalRungeKutta[];
ClassicalRungeKutta[___]["Step"[f_, t_, h_, y_, yp_]] := 
 Block[{deltay, k1, k2, k3, k4},
  k1 = yp;
  k2 = f[t + 1/2 h, y + 1/2 h k1];
  k3 = f[t + 1/2 h, y + 1/2 h k2];
  k4 = f[t + h, y + h k3];
  deltay = h (1/6 k1 + 1/3 k2 + 1/3 k3 + 1/6 k4);
  {h, deltay}
  ]; sol2 = 
 NDSolve[Join[eqs1, 
   Thread[{dd[[1]] U[y], dd[[2]] V[y], w[y], x[y]} == ini /. 
     y -> yc]], {U, V, w, x}, {y, yc, yfin}, 
  Method -> ClassicalRungeKutta, StartingStepSize -> 10^-5, 
  MaxSteps -> 2 10^5, AccuracyGoal -> 8, PrecisionGoal -> 8] 

and Stiffness solver as well
sol3 = NDSolve[
  Join[eqs1, 
   Thread[{dd[[1]] U[y], dd[[2]] V[y], w[y], x[y]} == ini /. 
     y -> yc]], {U, V, w, x}, {y, yc, yfin}, 
  Method -> {"StiffnessSwitching"}, StartingStepSize -> 10^-5, 
  MaxSteps -> 2 10^5, AccuracyGoal -> 8, PrecisionGoal -> 8]

Probably we need WhenEvent again to restrict w from crossing 0.

Thank you very much for the answer @AlexTrounev! I have several comments and questions.
The first: why "Z becomes very small and negative"? The evaluation should stop when Z is still positive
The second regards your right plot in the first figure: using your code I do not reproduce it, but I get something like the one in my question (so, nevermind).
The third is: I noticed that StiffnessSwitching would ruin your solution for Example 2, but at the same time not using this method would ruin Example 1. Why is that? This makes me not trust the solution in Example 2

@edinorog2196 Yes you are right about picture.  First, you should know how WhenEvent working in these examples before it makes last step. In your code there is a typo in WhenEvent syntactic. Therefore, the command "StopIntegration" is not executed.  And you cut your solution at tfin = 174. But if you put tfin = 175 then you will see that Z is complex.  This means that the restriction Z[t] < (3/2)^(-8/3) becomes meaningless.

I see. However the final solution varies if I change AccuracyGoal and PrecisionGoal and if I introduce StiffnessSwitching. Any idea why?

@edinorog2196 It is clear that we need to take the last step very carefully. It is necessary to transform the system to a new form in order to carefully pass the singularity. Since the system is autonomous, the number of equations can be reduced by using Z as a parameter. Note that we only use StiffnessSwitching when necessary.

I got rid of one equation and now I solve for y = -Log[Z] so the WhenEvent is not necessary anymore (I can stop at whenever arbitrary value). I edited the question, because I really think this problem is not about the WhenEvent. Could you have a look please?

@edinorog2196 Please, see Update 1 to my answer. :)

unfortunately I cannot reproduce your solution copy-pasting your code in a fresh notebook. I get FindRoot::jsing1: Encountered a singular Jacobian at the point {-1.72835*10^-7,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,0.,<<57770>>}. Try perturbing the initial point(s). FindRoot::sszero: The step size in the search has become less than the tolerance prescribed by the PrecisionGoal option, but the function value is still greater than the tolerance prescribed by the AccuracyGoal option. errors.

@edinorog2196 Very funny. My code doesn’t even contain FindRoot. Are you sure you copied my code and not something else? :)

yes, It is a fresh new notebook.. I am running Mathematica 13.0.1.0. Since I don't know what the "FiniteElement" method does I do not know how to fix the issue. The solution stops after a few iterations.

@edinorog2196 I am running v.14. See my post about mesh issues in v13 on  https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/282137/fem-code-working-well-in-v-12-1-has-warning-in-v-13-and-not-working-in-v-13-2

@edinorog2196 See Update 2 with solution without FEM.
